# Svelte does not update editable element on second update trigger

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

When using contentEditable attribute or value of input, svelte does only first update to the DOM. When I try trigger the update second time it does nothing.

- It does update non editable elements in the same scenario.
- Concatenating dynamic data like Date.now forces the update.

Is it svelte bug or am I missing something?

[Link to REPL Example](https://svelte.dev/repl/cfd6ad290cbb4e468edecf27d1235a1c?version=3.29.4)

Answer (score 0):

Use  `bind:innerHTML={value}` to bind value into content editable div. Check this [official repl from svelte](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/contenteditable-bindings)

```
<div contenteditable="true" bind:innerHTML={value}></div>
<div>{value}</div>
<button on:click={handle}>Update trigger</button>
```

Comment: But what if I don't want two-way binding? I don't want editing an element to cause an update on variable. All I want is to have an ability to rerender when value of the variable is changed.

Comment: First of all thanks for helping figuring this out ;) Above approach will indeed force rerender for simple values, but it won't help with objects. I've built a bit more complex [REPL example](https://svelte.dev/repl/4e234e238a3b400ca79e6889b6999276?version=3.29.4) with instructions and comments which dispose such issue.